# Go interface optimization

Tags: go

With reference to Russ Cox's December 2009 article, [Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

In the section on Memory Optimizations, Russ suggested that if the data being stored in the `interface{}` is smaller that the size of a `uintptr` then the value would be stored in the interface directly and no allocation of the data, followed by taking it's address would be needed.

If I test this with the following code: -

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type iface struct {
    _    unsafe.Pointer
    data unsafe.Pointer
}

func main() {
    var i interface{} = 12
    var pi = (*iface)(unsafe.Pointer(&i))
    fmt.Printf("if.data: %p", pi.data)
}
```

The result is: -

```
if.data: 0x127e2c
```

Clearly an address and not the value 12 that would be expected had the optimization been performed.

Does Go no longer support the interface optimization or am I missing something?

Comment: How interfaces are implemented is a compiler internal and might be even different between gc and gcc. Alos: Your test code relies on implementation details.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12128

Comment: There was a comment by PeterSO that I clicked on the up arrow to say that it added something useful and PeterSO's comment has disappeared. Don't know why that happened.

Comment: @collymy: I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Compiler And Runtime Optimizations**](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CompilerOptimizations)
>
> This page lists optimizations done by the compilers. Note that these
>   are not guaranteed by the language specification.
>
> **Interface values**
>
> **Word-sized value in an interface value**
>
> Putting a word-sized-or-less non-pointer type in an interface value
>   doesn't allocate.
>
> ```
> gc: 1.0-1.3, but not in 1.4+
> gccgo: never
> ```

---

Go no longer performs that optimization for Go1.4+.

Comment: For the qurious, that was done to enable GC being concurrent with the rest of the running code. See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8405) and [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/75b72b1b27dd74ca9a1ebdba22f545233431a99f) in particular.